# To search and return for unique string value counts in C# through input text file?

Tags: c#

I have a log file in the following format :

```
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:ashishg appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:ashishg appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User: ashishg appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:karansha appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:gulanand appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
INFO [SearchServices] WX Search = Server:nomos-scanner.corp.adobe.com User:ashishg appGUID: wx Elapsed Time:875ms SaveSearchID:361
```

Code that I have tried is :

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test file path");     
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();

List<string> users = new List<string>();
int numberOfUsers;

Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:(?<username>.*?) appGUID");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (!users.Contains(match.ToString())) users.Add(match.ToString());
}

Regex regex2 = new Regex(@"User: (?<username>.*?) appGUID");
matches = regex2.Matches(x);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    if (!users.Contains(match.ToString())) users.Add(match.ToString());
}

numberOfUsers = users.Count;
Console.WriteLine(numberOfUsers);
// keep screen from going away
// when run from VS.NET`
```

Comment: And what happens then?

Comment: What happens with your code? Looks fine to me (when running it, I mean)

Comment: Value it should return here is 3 but my program is returning 4, seems like it is taking "User:ashishg" and "User: ashishg" as 2 seperate values.

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention one thing, in this sample log, i am looking for unique User value counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the below code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"test file path");
string x = reader.ReadToEnd();
List<string> users = new List<string>();
Regex regex = new Regex(@"User:\s*(?<username>.*?)\s+appGUID");
MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(x);
foreach (Match match in matches) {
    var user = match.Groups["username"].Value;
    if (!users.Contains(user)) users.Add(user);
}
int numberOfUsers = users.Count;
Console.WriteLine(numberOfUsers);
```

I did the following two modifications:

1. You don't need two regular expressions. I edited it to cover both cases
2. You were accessing to the match, but in order to get the username, **you should be accessing to the `username` group**.

Comment: It worked. Many many Thanks Oscar for resolution. You are Genius.